# Role instances are taking longer than expected to start - Can't find solution is it a bug?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, azure, instances, webrole

I've been through this post: [Role instances are taking longer than expected to start - Is there a new solution to this problem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7051153/role-instances-are-taking-longer-than-expected-to-start-is-there-a-new-solutio)

But I can't find the answer why I am getting this error,  the emulator was working fine last week but today I found out it's not working I rebooted my PC and VS many times, and kept saying yes to dialog box but nothing works, I've also tried the post's solution, nothing has worked for me, I've also deleted recently added code, it's still the same.

I've started a new project and tried debugging unsuccesfully so I can surely say it's not a code problem.

Comment: What I did is to restore my system to a previous date, it worked fine (finally) but I don't know what caused the problem.