# Windows Azure - Role instances are taking longer than expected to start

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2012, azure

I was trying to run my Windows Azure project locally and, after running the project in Visual Studio 2012, it just sat there for a long time churning away and not displaying anything. After waiting for a while Visual Studio got bored and flashed the following warning:

> Role instances are taking longer than expected to start. Do you want
>   to continue waiting?

I tried continue many times. but still it is not displaying any thing.

Can anyone help me here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Role instances are taking longer than expected to start - Is there a new solution to this problem?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7051153/role-instances-are-taking-longer-than-expected-to-start-is-there-a-new-solutio)

Comment: @ Alastair Pitts, I tried those fixes but not yet resolved!!

Comment: do you have any `startup tasks`? If so, comment out all of them and try again!

Comment: @ astaykov, I tried that too. no result!

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked at the compute emulator UI for hints?

> To display the compute emulator user interface, open the shortcut menu for the Windows Azure icon in the notification area and then choose Show Compute Emulator UI.
>
> The left pane of the compute emulator UI shows the services currently deployed to the compute emulator and the role instances that each service is running. You can select the service or roles to display lifecycle, logging, and diagnostic information in the right pane. If you put the focus in the top margin of an included window, it expands to fill the right pane.