# Role Instances are taking longer than expected to start

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-storage

When I try to run ASP.net MVC app on Windows Azure emulator on local machine it gives below error.How can I get rid of this ?

[image]

**Error on Output window**

```
Windows Azure Tools: Warning: Remapping public port 80 to 81 to avoid conflict during emulation.
Windows Azure Tools: Warning: Remapping private port 80 to 82 in role 'PawLoyalty.Web' to avoid conflict during emulation.
Windows Azure Tools: Warning: Certificate identification setting 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.RemoteAccess.PasswordEncryption' for role 'PawLoyalty.Web' specified in the service configuration file is not declared in the service definition file in the Certificate or as part of an SSL endpont
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7051153/role-instances-are-taking-longer-than-expected-to-start-is-there-a-new-solutio.

Comment: What version of SDK are you using? Is there caching enabled in your roles?

Comment: @GauravMantri Ver 2.0,Yes caching enabled.

Comment: From time to time we also encountered this issue. What we did was disabled caching, ran the application (and it ran fine then) and enabled caching again (and it ran fine again). It's a really lame solution and may not work for you but please give it a try. Other thing you could do is delete the `cacheclusterconfigs` blob container in local storage emulator.

Comment: @GauravMantri Thanks.I just disabled the cache.Now it's working fine.If you can put this as a solution, I can accept it. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From time to time we also encountered this issue. By trial-and-error we found it to be caused by caching.

What we did was disabled caching, ran the application (and it ran fine then) and enabled caching again (and it ran fine again).

Its a really lame solution and may not work for you but please give it a try. Other thing you could do is delete the cacheclusterconfigs blob container in local storage emulator. Using a combination of these 2 usually resulted in the problem getting resolved.

[image]