# Role instances Issue while running webapi locally

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-cloud-services

I  have a webAPI deployed  on window azure, till last week I was able to run the WebAPI and debug but all of a sudden when I run the web application I get the below message.

> Role instances are taking longer than expected to start. Do you want
>   to continue waiting?

And I tried to enable disable caching(default caching is disable) and also cleared the local storage but still the same issue persist, its happening in not only my machine but also on other dev machine as well. Could it be because of automatic software updates related to emulator or other SW or any other issue?

Comment: I edited your question, removing a few non-essential things. However, doing a quick search myself, I found [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35369434/272109) to a near-identical question, posted a few weeks ago, which might answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Happened withh me today. I ran into an issue of the Azure emulator not working. The roles were going in a continuous loop of Running, Busy and Suspended.
Initially I thought it might be due to some code I had changed . However, it turned out that a recent Windows update had caused this issue.
After spending a frustrating amount of time un-installing the recent updates one by one, I found the miscreant.
For Fix please un-install the Security Update KB3126593 (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3126593).

While searching for the particular update, make sure you type “KB3126593” in the search bar. Typing 3126593 will not work.